# Getting random image from drawable directory with certain name suffix

Tags: android

I have various images in the res/drawable directory , i want to get a random image from it that has "module_" suffix, then load that into  a drawable object.The image names are not not named consecutively i.e 1 ,2 ,3 etc , they have different names describing what it contains i.e. "apple", "banana" etc
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think its possible to a get a random image from the drawable directory, so i just hard coded an array with the images and randomly index into that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 void populate() {
        try {

            ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (int i = 0; i <= 48; i++) // 1//
            {
                number.add(i + 1);
                Log.i("nuber in loop ",number.add(i+1)+"");
            }
            Collections.shuffle(number);
            Random r = new Random();
            int Start = r.nextInt(number.size());

            if (Start - 9 >= number.size() - 1)
                Start -= 9;
            Log.i("Start ",Start+"");

            for (int i = 0; i <=8; i++) 
            {

                 String imgName = "img" + number.get(Start);

                Log.i("imagename", imgName);
                int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable",
                        getPackageName());
                Log.i("id", id + "");
                ImgBtnArray[i].setImageResource(id);
                Start++;
            }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                        }
    }
```

into the above function it will
48 is total no of images into drwable from thatany 9 randm img i'll get and it will check for not to allow duplicate no also

in to the above i've 1 to 49 imgs into sequence 1.png,2.png lyk that that is more easy way.. i think bt u can create string array may be this way u can do

Comment: As i mentioned before the images are not named sequentially 1,2,3 etc, since the drawable cant have sub directories i need to keep the naming i have now, i use the image name for dynamically loading text. I dont want to have to maintain a string array with all the names since images are added or deleted from the directory